# Testing if an Array is empty JUNIT

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I wanna write a Method displaying a deck from a Game.
I initialized an `Array` with 98 Elements

```
private int [] cards = new int[98];
```

I also created a get and a set method

```
public int[] getCards() {
    return cards;
}
```

and

```
public void setCards(final int... cards) {
    this.cards = cards;
}
```

The Method I wrote is called `drawCard`. If I use this method it should remove the first element out of the `Array` and return it.

```
public int drawCard() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (getCards().length == 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("No Cards Left!");
    }
    setCards(ArrayUtils.removeElement(getCards(), 0));
    return getCards()[0];
}
```

And then I wrote the JUnit Test.
The test should remove all the 98 elements and then the array should be empty `== 0`.
But the test always stops at 1.

```
@Test
public void testDrawCard() {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    assertThat(deck.getCards().length).isEqualTo(98);

    for(int x = 98; x >= 0; x--){
        deck.drawCard();
    }
    assertThat(deck.getCards().length).isEqualTo(0);
}
```

**Error message:**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at edu.hm.hafner.java2.thegame.Deck.drawCard(Deck.java:35)
```

> 35=Return Line

```
at edu.hm.hafner.java2.thegame.DeckTest.testDrawCard(DeckTest.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Does somebody know what's wrong?

Comment: You are looping from 98 to ! inclusively ! 0.

Comment: You are trying to remove 99 elements.

Comment: Just change the >= to a simple >

Comment: change loop to `for(int x = 98; x > 0; x--){`

Comment: If you're constantly resizing, just use `ArrayList`. The method you're using will incur substantial overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ajb is right, but when you want to normally iterate backwards, you start with **length - 1** because indices start with 0. So in your style, the loop should be

```
for(int x = 98 - 1; x >= 0; x--)
```

But however, you aren't using the x variable inside the loop, so the order should not matter as long as you are drawing exactly 98 elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int x = 98; x >= 0; x--)
```

This executes the loop while `x >= 0`.  That is, if we decrement `x` and it gets the value 0, we execute the loop again because `0 >= 0` is true.  Then, we decrement `x` and find that it's -1, so the loop stops.  This means that the loop will execute for `x` = 98, 97, 96, ..., 2, 1, 0.  There are 99 numbers in this list, so the loop executes 99 times.

Since you're not using `x` at all, there's no reason to have it start at the top and go downward.  If the only purpose is to make sure your loop is executed exactly 98 times, then don't get clever--just use the standard `for` loop idiom:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 98; i++)
```

It doesn't make a difference to the program's execution.  But by sticking to the standard idioms except when necessary, you'll save some brain cells and end up with a lot fewer bugs to figure out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But if I change the loop to 
`i= 0, i <98, i++` I still get the same exception

The error message always tells me there is something wrong with the return statement but I don't get it

Comment: Does the error message say, literally, "There is something wrong with the return statement"?  Or does it provide more information?  Please don't hide important information from us.  Even if you don't understand what it means, the rest of us will.  So don't keep secrets from us.

Comment: So I just edited the test method 
`@Test
    public void testDrawCard() {
        Deck deck = new Deck();

        assertThat(deck.getCards().length).isEqualTo(98);


        for (int i = 0; i < 98; i++){
            deck.drawCard();
        }

        assertThat(deck.getCards().length).isEqualTo(0);

    }`

But the Error is still

 `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

 at edu.hm.hafner.java2.thegame.Deck.drawCard(Deck.java:35)
 at edu.hm.hafner.java2.thegame.DeckTest.testDrawCard(DeckTest.java:40)`

Comment: You still haven't answered my question.

Comment: Well this is the only information IntelliJ is providing me

Comment: You edited your comment after I responded to it.  Your error is that you're trying to return an element from the deck _after_ you have removed all the elements and the length is now 0.